# regular expression for parentheses within quotes

Tags: python

I want to split a string into several parts in parentheses, but the quoted things (possibly including parentheses) should be treated as a single symbol. For example, the string

(id1, "Hello simple"), (id2, "Hello \n weird (all chars) Ä@")

should be split into two parts

1) id1, "Hello simple"

2) id2, "Hello \n weird (all chars) Ä@"

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: Look into python's split [module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit)

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use `regex`, this works with the current string from your post:

```
import re
pat = re.compile(r'\(([a-zA-Z0-9"\(\)\s]+)\)')
matches = re.findall(pat, '(Hello "(world)"), (2016)')
# ['Hello "(world)"', '2016']
```

However, the `split` function may also be a viable options for the format of text. If all data is surrounded by a single pair of parantheses, you can do:

```
results = [x[1:-1] for x in '(Hello "(world)"), (2016)'.split(', ')]
# ['Hello "(world)"', '2016']
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems I over-simplify the problem. Could you have a look at the edited question? Basically, things inside quotes can be any symbol, including escapes and unicodes. Also comma can appear inside each split part.